# It's possible to display "User" menu history like "Entries" menu history on admin dashboard

Tags: craft3, admin, custom, dashboard-widgets

[image]

Or, Is there any way to modify the recent entries widget and display user history in the same widget

Comment: What exactly would you expect to appear in user history? A list of recently created users?

Comment: Yes, I want recently created, updated and deleted users history.

Answer (score 2):

For something like the Entries widget, you'll need to code your own custom widget. There's instructions you can dig into here:

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/widget-types.html

The queries you'll need to run to get users are here:

https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/users.html#querying-users

here's where you can add a User's widget to your dashboard. This will show user numbers in a line graph. Once you make a new widget type, it will show up in this menu too.

[image]

Hope this helps!